# Segmentation Fault issue, unable to detect

Tags: c

Can someone help me with this piece of code. I am getting segmentation fault. Kindly help me out as to where I am going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct city
{
    int x;
    int pop;
    struct city *next;
};
struct list
{
    struct city *head;
};

void insert(struct list *list1,int a,int b)
{
    struct city *node = (struct city *)malloc(sizeof(struct city));
    node->x=a;
    node->pop = b;
    if(list1->head!=NULL)
    {
        node->next=list1->head;
    }
    list1->head=node;
}

void initialize_list(struct list *list1)
{
    list1->head = NULL;
}

void display(struct list *list)
{
    struct city *temp = list->head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n",temp->x,temp->pop);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    free(temp);
}
void getdata(int *x)
{
    char s[1000];
    char c;

    scanf("%[^\n]%*s",s);

    char *p=s;
    int i =0;
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        while(*p==' ' && *p!='\0')
            p++;
        if(*p!='\0')
            x[i] = atoi(p);
        while(*p!=' ' && *p!='\0')
            p++;
        i++;
    }
}
int max(int a,int b)
{
    if(a>b)
        return a;
    else
        return b;
}

int total(struct list *link)
{
    struct city *r1,*r2;
    r1=link->head;
    r2 = r1;
    int S=0;
    while(r1!=NULL)
    {
        r2 = r1;
        while(r2!=NULL)
        {   
            S=S+max(r1->pop,r2->pop)*abs((r2->x)-(r1->x));
            r2=r2->next;
        }
        r1=r1->next;

    }
    printf("\n%d",S);
    free(r1);
    free(r2);
    return S;
}

int main()
{
    int T;
    int *x,*pop;
    int _no_city;
    char c;
    scanf("%d",&T);

    struct list **link = (struct list **)malloc(T*sizeof(struct list*));
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        link[i]=(struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    }

    for(int i =0;i<T;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&_no_city);

        x = (int *)malloc(_no_city*sizeof(int));
        pop = (int *)malloc(_no_city*sizeof(int));
        while((c= getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)

        fflush(stdin);
        getdata(x);
        getdata(pop);

        initialize_list(link[i]);
        for(int j=0;i<_no_city;j++)
        {
            insert(link[i],x[j],pop[j]);
        }
        free(x);
        free(pop);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
    {
        printf("%d",total(link[i]));
    }
}
```

Is the problem lying with my declaring a pointer to pointer, I did that so that I can create an array of pointers of variable length.

Comment: Any debugger should be able to help you walk through and identify the section of code generating the error.  Once you know that if you cannot determine the cause, you can provide a smaller code example we can help you with.

Comment: Consider some comments or other explanation of your code as well.  The while loop in your main function is particularly puzzling.

Comment: Are you aware that a) you're flushing stdin for every char you read? b) flushing input streams is undefined behavior c) this will infinite loop on machines where char is unsigned because `c` isn't big enough to hold EOF (which is an `int`)? Of course that's not the cause of your crash. Learn the basics of debugging, or learn a different language ... it's almost 2016 and there's no excuse for using C ... especially the way you're writing in it.

Comment: You seem to be confused about how `free` works. There should be exactly one `free` for each `malloc`. And you should only call `free` when you're done with the memory that `malloc` gave you.

Comment: Oh, hey, this is certainly a bug: `for(int j=0;i<_no_city;j++)` ... learn to put spaces around operators instead of cramming everything together like that and it will be easier to see. And for FSM's sake don't start variable names with underscores.

Comment: Yeah, the frees in `display` and `total` are nonsensical, but it's hard to make sense of any of this. Either pick meaningful names, or document the semantics of everything. (The former is preferred where possible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few bugs in your program, but this one

> ```
> for(int j=0;i<_no_city;j++)
> {
>     insert(link[i],x[j],pop[j]);
> }
> ```

will run off the end of `x` and `pop` because your loop condition is wrong, and is probably the cause of your crash.